# Warning: Failed value type: The value `isRequired` is marked as required in `Select`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, antd

> index.js:2178 Warning: Failed value type: The value `isRequired` is marked as required in `Select`, but its value is `undefined`.
>
> index.js:2178 Warning: Failed defaultValue type: The defaultValue `isRequired` is marked as required in `Select`, but its value is `undefined`.

React 16.7

```
<Form layout="inline">
   <Form.Item>
      {
           getFieldDecorator('select')(
                 <Select placeholder='choose' style={{ width: 100 }} onChange={this.selectPuzzle}>
                      {options}
                 </Select>
              )
       }
   </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per `antd` documentation,
it should be

```
{
  getFieldDecorator("select", {
    rules: [{ required: true, message: "Your message" }]
  })(
    <Select
      placeholder="choose"
      style={{ width: 100 }}
      onChange={this.selectPuzzle}
    >
      {options}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

Link for refenrence: https://ant.design/components/form/